# How to search a list for elements of a tuple?

Tags: list, f#, tuples, return-value

For my assignment, I have to take a list of tuples of people at a wedding who can't sit next to each other. Then compare it with a list of people at a table. If any two people in the same tuple are in the table list, then it should be false. Otherwise true. This is my first time coding in F# so the syntax is killing me here.

```
let isValidTable (cantSit:(string*string) list) (people: string list) =

    let truth = true;
    let rec matchPeople cantSit person1 person2= 
        match cantSit with
        | [] -> None
        | head :: tail ->
            let (person1,person2) = head 
            if ((List.exists(fun names -> names = person1) people) && (List.exists(fun names2 -> names2 = person2) people)) then
                let result2 = false
            else 
                matchPeople tail fst snd;;
                let result = true;;
    matchPeople cantSit fst snd;;


let x = [("Eric", "Mark"); ("Anna", "Maya"); ("Beth", "Hope")];; 
let weddingList = ["Eric"; "Anna"; "Beth"]
let validOrNah = isValidTable x weddingList;;
printf("\n%O") validOrNah;;
```

The problem for me is that I keep getting errors like "matchPeople constructor not defined", or "let is unfinished". Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Before: I had

```
if(first person is in list and second person is in list)
then Some false
else recursive statement;
```

This code compiled without errors but only printed null. I know variables are immutable in F#, which is making this tough.

Comment: Why are you seemingly randomly scattering `;;` around? And what is `result2` and `result` supposed to be used for? This looks a bit like something a Shakespearian monkey might have cobbled together.

Comment: @glennsl As silly as this may sound, it saved me from some "let unfinished" errors, result2 and result one are intended to be the boolean return values. But Im not sure how to get them to do that.

Comment: Well, I don't think randomly mashing things together is a good strategy, so maybe don't do that. There is no "returning" values in an expression-based language, at least in the sense that you terminate early with a result, just expressions that evaluate to values. `false` evaluates to `false`, so that's all you need. Just remove the unfinished let binding that you're not using for anything, and the error about "let unfinished" will go away too.

Comment: When you call `matchPeople tail fst snd`, what do you expect it to do, given that you haven't defined the names `fst` and `snd`? There are F# functions called `fst` and `snd`, but I don't think you're intending to pass those functions as parameters.

Answer (score 7):

There are many problems in your code, all caused by your unfamiliarity with F#. I'll go through it line by line and try to explain what you haven't yet understood.

```
let isValidTable (cantSit:(string*string) list) (people: string list) =
```

This is fine.

```
    let truth = true;
```

There's no need for this assignment at all, since you never use the name `truth` anywhere else in your code. And if you did need to use it, you could just replace it with the constant `true` and it would read better. Let's remove this line entirely.

BTW, there's no need for semicolons at the end of lines in F#, unlike in C-like languages. The double semicolon is only used in the F# Interactive interpreter, to tell the interpreter "I'm done entering this expression". This allows you to split an expression across multiple lines, without the interpreter needing to guess when you're done (because many partial expressions in F# can *look* complete, so explicit expression termination is needed). I won't mention this every time a semicolon comes up, but you can remove all semicolons (and double semicolons) at the end of your lines. The only place a semicolon is *needed* in F# is between items in a list, such as in `x` or in `weddingList`.

On to the next line.

```
    let rec matchPeople cantSit person1 person2=
```

This looks fine, but in fact, you don't need the `person1` and `person2` parameters at all. My guess is that you have them in the parameter list because you think you need to declare variables before you create them, but that's not how F# works at all. When you write `let (person1, person2) = head` later in the function, the variables `person1` and `person2` are created right there, and there's no need to have them as function parameters. So you can remove them, and your function definition will become `let rec matchPeople cantSit =`

```
        match cantSit with
```

This is fine.

```
        | [] -> None
```

This is a minor mistake. Elsewhere you look like you want to return a Boolean value, but here you return an option instead. In F#, *all* branches of `match` and/or `if...else` must return the same type. Your `isValidTable` function clearly is intended to return a Boolean, and so is `matchPeople`, so this should be a Boolean value as well. The question is, should this line return `false` or `true`? To answer that question, think about what an empty `cantSit` list means in the semantics of your problem domain. It would mean that there is nobody who can't sit with each other, so the seating list is valid no matter who's at the table. Or, of course, it could also mean that you've reached the end of the `cantSit` list by multiple recursive calls, in which case the value you return here will be the value you return finally from the last recursive call. And again, returning `true` is what you want, because if you had found an invalid sitting pair earlier, you would have returned `false` immediately and not made another recursive call. So if you get to the point where the `cantSit` list is empty, then you're ready to return `true`.

```
        | head :: tail ->
```

This is fine.

```
            let (person1,person2) = head
```

This is not just fine, it's quite good.

```
            if ((List.exists(fun names -> names = person1) people) && (List.exists(fun names2 -> names2 = person2) people)) then
```

This is fine, but could be simplified. There's a `List.contains` function that does what you want here. Any call of the type `List.exists (fun item -> item = value) itemList)` can be simplified to `List.contains item itemList`. So this would become `if (List.contains person1 people) && (List.contains person2 people) then`, which is much easier to read and understand quickly.

```
                let result2 = false
```

This is incorrect; a `let` assignment in F# has no value, and since it's the last expression in the `if` block, that means the `if` block would not have a value if its condition turns out to be true. This is why you're getting the "unfinished" errors: in F#, a `let` assignment *may never be the last expression of a code block*. It must always be followed by an expression that has a value. What you're actually trying to do here is pretty clear: you want to return `false` if both people are in the list. You can do that by just writing `false` in this line; I'll explain a little more here.

In F#, `if...else` is an *expression that returns a value*, not a statement like it is in most other languages. So you can write something like this:

```
let n = 5
let s = if n % 2 = 0 then "Even" else "Odd"
printfn "%s" s  // Prints "Odd"
```

Here, your `if...else` is the last line of one case of the `match` expression, so its value will be the value of the `match` expression. And the `match` expression is the last expression of the `matchPeople` function, so its value will be the return value of the function. So in the case where you find a matching pair that can't sit together (the true branch of this `if...else` expression), then you just have to have a line saying `false`, and that will be the return value of the function if it hits that branch.

Moving on to your next line.

```
            else
```

This is fine, obviously.

```
                matchPeople tail fst snd;;
```

This is fine once you remove the `fst` and `snd` (since we changed our function signature so that `matchPeople` now takes just one argument), and remove the semicolons as mentioned previously.

```
                let result = true;;
```

Same comment as for the earlier `let result2 = false` line: a `let` assignment may never be the last line of a code block in F#. Here, what you want to do is let the result of the recursive `matchPeople` call be the final result of your "outer" level of recursion. You can do that by simply deleting this `let result = true` line, so that the `matchPeople` call is the last line of the `else` block. That means that its result will be the result of the `else` block, and since the `if...else` expression is the last expression of this case of `match`, the recursive call will be the last expression of the `match` statement. And since the `match` statement is the last expression of the `matchPeople` function, its result will also be the result of the overall function (if the code reaches the `else` branch). That means that this recursive call is in **tail position**, which is an important concept later: a call is in tail position if its result will be the result of the overall function. A call in tail position is usually known as a "tail call" for short. I won't go into depth about tail calls here, except to say that a tail call can be optimized by the compiler so that it will never cause a stack overflow error, no matter how many times you go through the recursive call. For now, we'll put tail calls aside and go on to look at the rest of your code:

```
    matchPeople cantSit fst snd;;
```

As with the other call, just remove the `fst` and `snd` parameters (and the double semicolon) and this will be fine.

```
let x = [("Eric", "Mark"); ("Anna", "Maya"); ("Beth", "Hope")];; 
let weddingList = ["Eric"; "Anna"; "Beth"]
let validOrNah = isValidTable x weddingList;;
printf("\n%O") validOrNah;;
```

All of this is fine once you remove the unnecessary double semicolons. I'd probably write `printfn "%O" validOrNah` on the last line, but that's personal preference: I like to print a newline at the end of my output, rather than the beginning (`printfn` prints a newline after whatever you ask it to print, while `printf` without a trailing `n` in the function name does not print a trailing newline). But what you have written here is fine.

Making all those changes, here's what your code turns into:

```
let isValidTable (cantSit:(string*string) list) (people: string list) =

    let rec matchPeople cantSit =
        match cantSit with
        | [] -> true
        | head :: tail ->
            let (person1,person2) = head 
            if (List.contains person1 people) && (List.contains person2 people) then
                false
            else 
                matchPeople tail
    matchPeople cantSit

let x = [("Eric", "Mark"); ("Anna", "Maya"); ("Beth", "Hope")]
let weddingList = ["Eric"; "Anna"; "Beth"]
let validOrNah = isValidTable x weddingList
printfn "%O" validOrNah
```

I made no changes to your logic since it's correct (well done!), so once you make these syntax fixes that I suggested, this should run and print the correct results.